# Programmatically created button's onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a button through JavaScript and am trying to assign it to an onclick event. At runtime the button is created but the `onclick` event isn't firing when I click it. Also in Chrome's Inspector, no error is generated when I click the button.

Here's my code:

```
function truncator(){
      $.each($('td.rawdata-field').not(':empty'), function(i,v){
        var count = parseInt($(v).text().length);
        var maxChars = 650;
        if(count > maxChars){
          var str = $(v).text();
          var trimmed = str.substr(0, maxChars - 2);
          $(v).text(trimmed + '...');

          var btn = document.createElement('button');

          btn.setAttribute('content', 'test content');
          btn.setAttribute('class', 'show-full-text-button');
          btn.innerHTML = 'Show Full Log';

          btn.onclick = function() {
              alert("assd");
          };

          $(v).append(btn);
        }  
      });
    };
```

`v` is the parent container, which in this case is a `td` element.

What's the problem here?

**EDIT:
One additional detail I can offer is that the above is being executed many times over a page, which is have something to do with why it isn't working. All the buttons are being created fine, but the alert's aren't working when done through the above method.**

The container already exists when the above code is executed.

**EDIT 2:
I've updated the code above to include more of what is going on. The function `truncator` basically is supposed to go through all `td` elements with class `rawdata-field` that are not empty, and check if the text mentioned in it is longer than 650 characters. If it is, it truncates the text to 650 characters and then puts a button there to showing the complete log if the user wishes to do so.
The table on which the above function operates already exists when `truncator` is called.**

Comment: are you looking for jquery solution or pure js only because if you dont we need to remove jquery tag

Comment: Either is fine, whichever is more concise.

Comment: well if you want a jquery solution you can have something like this `$(document).on('click','.show-full-text-button',function(){alert('hello')})`

Comment: Your code is working fine on my end when [I test it](https://jsfiddle.net/mpxh70xc/) with some dummy HTML. Are you sure that this script is running after `v` has been initialized? Perhaps you could move it to the bottom of your `<body>` to be sure?

Comment: @guardio ... Your solution works but since `.show-full-text-button` class is being used by many buttons on my page, it creates a lot of identical popups. If you can somehow refer to the button using the variable name `btn` instead, I think it will solve this problem.

Comment: inside the click you can use this context like `$(this)` that will refer to the click button with the class `.show-full-text-button`

Comment: Don't understand. Can you give a code sample ?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','.show-full-text-button',function(){alert($(this).text())})` this is give you the text of clicked element with the class `.show-full-text-button`

Comment: @Ahmad add an unique Id for your buttons, see my answer

Comment: I've updated the code in my post to include more of what is going on.

Comment: @Ahmad You use button onclick, it's pure js. So the class has no role here. Unless you do something with ".show-full-text-button"

Answer (score 0):

Your code work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/dusfqtr9/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');

    btn.setAttribute('content', 'test content');
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'show-full-text-button');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Show Full Log';
    btn.onclick = function() {
        alert("Hello !");
    };
    $("#container").append(btn);
  });
```

Maybe your script is run before the parent container created, so $(v).append(btn) do nothing.

Comment: See my new comments above in case they help.

Comment: Code updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/dusfqtr9/1/. You should detail more about process flow, and what do you try to do, that will help.

Comment: I've updated the code in my post to include more of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` only works with the elements that already exist at the time when the script (containing your onclick handler) is loaded. As such, elements that get created after that, are no longer bound to the `onclick` event that you specified in the loaded script.

I'm not sure what your full code set is, but I'm guessing that your button is regenerated probably several times *after* the script is loaded. This is the most likely reason why the `onclick` event does not fire.

As such, what you would want to do is to "attach" the event handler to a higher level in the DOM tree (highest being your html) that you are sure won't get 'programmatically' regenerated, then you'd want to check if the element in question, which is inside the DOM, exists. You then run your function when this element is found.

Below is a JQuery implementation of this logic using the `.on` :

**EDIT1:** I've edited the code based on your latest comment.  You'll notice that I've separated the function that handles the click of your buttons.  I urge you to **try doing this in your original code set, and you'll see that the onclick event will *always* be bound to your buttons regardless of when your buttons are created, or even how many times you regenerate them.**

**EDIT2:** I just noticed in the comments that you wanted to show the full text in the alert. Edited the code to show one way of doing that.

```js
function truncator(){
      $.each($('td.rawdata-field').not(':empty'), function(i,v){
        var origContent = $(v).text();
       $(v).attr('orig-content',origContent);
        var count = parseInt($(v).text().length);
        var maxChars = 10;
        if(count > maxChars){
          var str = $(v).text();
          var trimmed = str.substr(0, maxChars - 2);
          $(v).text(trimmed + '...');

          var btn = document.createElement('button');

          btn.setAttribute('content', 'test-content');
          btn.setAttribute('class', 'show-full-text-button');
          btn.innerHTML = 'Show Full Log';         
          $(v).append(btn);
        }  
      });
    };

    $('html').on('click', '.show-full-text-button', function(){
      content = $(this).closest('td').attr('orig-content');
      alert(content);
    });

    truncator();
```

```css
table td {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="rawdata-field"> this is a very long text </td>
  <td class="rawdata-field"> another long text </td>
  <td class="rawdata-field"> this is getting out ofhand </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="rawdata-field"> okay another longtext </td>
  <td class="rawdata-field"> more content here, and there's another one here </td>
  <td class="rawdata-field"> what am i doing here </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using `onclick` works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpxh70xc/) even though it's used before the element has been appended to the page.

Comment: I've updated the code in my post to include more of what is going on.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on what I think you're trying to do. See my updated answer. Is this what you had in mind?